# Doctrine 2.1 - Recording activities throughout entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

i want to be able to record actions a logged in user does...  persist / updates etc

i have set up discriminators etc  and it works perfect however, it only records on all new persisted data...
so i have info on a table called user_actions,
1 - Added a new customer,
2 - Added a new memo
etc

however, it doesnt record any updates to entities on my db...
such as 1 - Updated user  - id 1
...

i am thinking of dumping the discriminator superclass and use a the old way to record,,,... like create a table with the fields:
id  |   action type |  description |  user ID | date

im not sure, what is the best way to log all transactions in doctrine 2.1?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider of `HasLifecycleCallbacks`? You can track not only `PostPersist` but also `PostUpdate` and `PostRemove`(or even `Pre*`)

Comment: yes, i have them but what will i do to record them... isnt there an extention like loggable or something?  i want the best efficient way to store these actions.. i can always result to creating a table called actions and dumping them into there but there must be an efficient and better way.

Comment: ok I see. I have no clue other than the idea you have creating actions  table. I would do either record all actions by LifecycleCallbacks or DB triggers. I haven't seen any extension or something that does it sorry. It sounds tough to be an extension since any service may have customized actions and DB structure, in my opinion